# nativescript "Install Android SDK Platform 25" failed

Tags: android, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am creating an app using nativescript. I have add the android platform as follows

`tns platform add android --sdk 22`

as I want to build for API level 22.

And when I build the app I get the following error.

```
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
"Install Android SDK Platform 25" failed.
```

Where is it getting SDK platform 25 from?
How can I overcome this?

Also, do mention how can I build for a specific API level.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short version:**

Add a platform - `tns platform add android`
State desired compileSdk during build - `tns run android --compileSdk 22` or `tns build android --compileSdk 22`

**Longer version:**

Adding the android platform to a {N} project only creates the android-studio-project structure. When the gradle script is invoked, the {N} CLI will pass along compileSdk, targetSdk, support libraries version flags to the build.

So doing `tns platform add` android is enough to bootstrap the project structure.

When building/running your project: By default, the CLI reads the $ANDROID_HOME/platforms directory to see what Android API level sdks are installed, and will work with the latest supported version. Say if I had android-22, android-23, android-25, android-26, the project will be built against compileSdk 26. If, your latest installed is android-22, then that will be the version your android project will be built against.

But what if you have other platform levels installed? Well, when building/running an android project, you can supply the --compileSdk flag followed by your desired version, and the gradle build will pick that up.

`tns run android --compileSdk` 22 is what you should run to get the desired results in your case, I assume.

Alternatively, you could override any, or at least most of the Android settings by writing gradle configuration inside the app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle script, where changes are persistent.

Copied response from https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/nativescript-building-for-a-specific-api-level-android/2140/2?u=pete.k